# Tycho Build: Depencency plugins are deployed as flat directory instead of jar

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I'm facing with following problem in my project. I have an own plugin which have a required plugin: org.eclipse.emf.ecp.view.treemasterdetail.validation

It follows that after tycho build in my product the plugins folder have such a file:

(...)\plugins\org.eclipse.emf.ecp.view.treemasterdetail.validation_1.14.0.20170911-0944\org\eclipse\emf\ecp\view\treemasterdetail\internal\validation\TreeMasterDetailValidationInitiator$TreeMasterDetailValidationInitiatorDomainChangeListener.class

As you can imagine in Windows OS it can be a problem (because of very long file path). What I do not understand is that in my eclipse instance and in p2 repo this plugin is deployed as a .jar why then in my build it is unpacked ?

Can I configure it somehow to keep this plugin as a JAR ?

I tried to put it into my feature.xml directly with unpack false

```
<plugin
     id="org.eclipse.emf.ecp.view.treemasterdetail.validation"
     download-size="0"
     install-size="0"
     version="1.14.0.20170911-0944"
     unpack="false"/>
```

But it also did not help.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for this option: Eclipse-BundleShape

You need to place it in your MANIFEST.MF file, the options are 'jar' and 'dir'. In your case:

```
Eclipse-BundleShape: jar
```

I've found in this [thread](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=314962) that you have to place it at the very last line of the MANIFEST.MF or it won't have any effect because of a bug.

Comment: Hi, thanks for fast answer. Nevertheless the plugin in which the problem occurs is just a dependency which my plugin uses. It is provided by the eclipse, so I'm not able to change it's manifest. I tried to edit the manifest of that plugin in P2 repository, but unfortunately it did not help.